# Display Total of Stacked Columns

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I have the following setting in reporting to display the total of stacked column:
[image]

I also tried, [[total]], "[[total]]" etc..

But I get:

[image]

Which is the same value as the last column.

What is the correct way to display the total value of the stacked columns ?

EDIT1:

Tried the first proposed solution and it gave the following:

[image]

where all labels are formatted with the same text.

Answer (score 0):

For achieve this result you need:

1) Add "[[total]]" in "Total Text" field, in value axis advanced settings
[image]

2) Next you should override "Label Function" in Graph settings.
[image]
[image]

The code of function

```
 /**
 * Return label text
 */

function(graphDataItem, formattedText) {
    var total = graphDataItem.values.total;
    var formattedTotal = AmCharts.formatNumber(total, { 
        precision: 2,
        decimalSeparator: ".",
        thousandsSeparator: " "
    }, 2);
    return formattedTotal;
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. All the labels inside now all have the same values set as total, so in your case, all the blue, yellow, red etc... labels (if you display them) will be set to the total value.